# packaging maven project jboss fuse

Tags: jboss, maven-3, jbossfuse, fuseesb

In my project I connect to a mysql database. To deploy my jar on jboss fuse I need to add mysql-connector-java to the deploy folder. Do you have an idea how to package my project to deliver a single jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To embed a jar inside your bundle do the following:

1) Declare it as a dependency

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.your.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>your-needed-jar</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

2) Tell [maven-bundle-plugin](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) to embed it.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Embed-Dependency>your-needed-jar</Embed-Dependency>
                    <Import-Package>
                        eventually.unneded.pkg;resolution:="optional",
                        *
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Export-Package>
                        com.your.company.app.exportedpkg
                    </Export-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

While this work in general cases, there may be classloading issues with libraries which do a lot of runtime class proxying and class generation (like ORMs).

IMHO a better approach would be to make the library available from JBoss Fuse itself. To do so:
1) copy `mysql-connector-java-xxx.java` in JBoss Fuse lib/ directory
2) edit `config.properties` in JBoss etc/ Fuse directory
3) add `com.mysql.jdbc` package to the list

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages= \
 ...
 org.apache.karaf.diagnostic.core;version="2.4.0.redhat-621084", \
 com.mysql.jdbc;version="xxx", \
```

Now you don't need to embed the library in your bundle, you can directly import it. The system bundle (ID:0) is exporting it.

For further reference this PDF document may provide helpful information: [Red Hat JBoss Fuse 6.2 Managing OSGi Dependencies](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.2/pdf/Managing_OSGi_Dependencies/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse-6.2-Managing_OSGi_Dependencies-en-US.pdf)